# Как сделать объект класса A членом класса B?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

**Как сделать объект класса A членом класса B?**
Сейчас поясню свою мысль:

```
class A {

}
class B {
    private:
    A A_object;
    public:
    B(){
       this->A_object = /* Что мне написать, чтоб в конструкторе присвоить переменной A_object объект класса A?  */
    }

}
```

Я осознаю,что вопрос тупой. Но я новичок в си подобных языках, раньше писал только на python, а там чтоб создать объект класса, достаточно написать A() (где A - это название класса). Ну а в C++ я не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял - то ничего не надо писать. Объект создается сам, конструктором по умолчанию.

Если бы ситуация была сложнее - например,

```
class A {
public:
    A(int a) { ...}
}
```

то тогда можно было бы указать параметр для этого конструктора, скажем, так:

```
class B {
private:
    A A_object;
public:
    B(int a):A_object(a)
    {
        ...
```

Comment: Какой именно? В этой переменной **уже** есть объект. Если бы это был *указатель* - `A* A_object`, тогда да, его надо было бы инициализировать, скажем, `B():A_object(new A) {...` В вашем варианте - не нужно ничего.

Comment: Кхм, я сам запутался. Извиняюс

Comment: Спасибо, что пояснили синтаксис B(int a) : A_object(a), он мне тоже был не понятен и я не знал что загуглить.

Comment: @NewView Исправил.

Comment: @КириллЛеонтьев Initialization list.